# Java: Reading the same file from different threads sometimes returns null content in some of the threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, inputstream, bufferedreader

First of all, I am pretty new in coding, so I apologise for any argot-mistake I am probably making

I am working on the development of a backend server using **Java (openJDK11)** and **Spring boot**:

The application is composed by many panels and sub-panels, which are opened from the web browser. When clicking a sub-panel, three different GET requests are performed in front-end side.

These three requests expect different responses (json schema, json data, etc). Each request starts a different thread that access **the same config file** (there is one config file per sub-panel), which is parsed. After reading the config file, each thread does different operations, they only have in common the config-reader part.

- Sometimes (this makes me think of concurrency), the read-operation in one/some of these threads cannot be performed, since `bufferedReader.readLine()` returns **null** without reading any line.
- Also, sometimes happens that after reading correctly some lines, suddenly `bufferedReader.readLine()` returns **null**, but the file has not been completely read yet.

Each thread creates a local `InputStream` to open the file, and a local `BufferedReader` to parse it.

I have tried making **synchronized** the `parseFile` method (although I feel this is not right, since I don't want other threads that use this method -to read other files- to wait).

Below are included the pieces of code were the file is accessed and read (line by line). **This is a "reduced" example**. As commented below by some users, Exceptions are not handled here, but **are** in the real code. This is only to show the part that is causing trouble.

```java
// REST CONTROLLER

@GetMapping(value = "/schema/{panel}/{subpanel}")
public PanelSchemaEntity getSchema(String panel, String subpanel)
{
  //Retrieves the config-file name associated to the given panel+subpanel
  String fileName = getConfig(panel, subpanel);
  // fileName = "target/config/panelABC1.txt"

  InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  PanelSchemaEntity schema = new PanelSchemaEntity();
  parseFile(schema, input);

  return schema;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/data/{panel}/{subpanel}")
public PanelDataEntity get(String panel, String subpanel)
{
  //Retrieves the config-file name associated to the given panel+subpanel
  String fileName = getConfig(panel, subpanel);
  // fileName = "target/config/panelABC1.txt"

  InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  PanelSchemaEntity schema = new PanelSchemaEntity();
  parseFile(schema, input);

  String dataFileName = getDataFile(panel, subpanel);
  // dataFileName = "target/config/panelABC1.dat"
  InputStream data = new FileInputStream(dataFileName);

  return new PanelDataEntity(schema, data);
}
```

```java
// PLACED IN SOME UTILS PACKAGE

// Fills the PanelSchemaEntity with the content read from input
public PanelSchemaEntity parseFile(PanelSchemaEntity schema, InputStream input)
{
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
  String nextLine = reader.readLine();

  // The data file is read and used to complete panel schema entity
  while(nextLine != null)
  {
    // Here goes the code that uses each line's content to 
    // fill some schema's attributes
  }
  reader.close();
  return schema;
}
```

Sorry again for any mistake I am possibly making, and thank you all :)

#### EDIT

- The file to be read multiple times is small but **cannot be stored in cache**, since it is related to a panel which may not be opened again soon. Also, there are too many config files (one per sub-panel) to be cached and each file may change
- I strongly prefer not to include new libraries, since I have not permission to do this, I only need to fix this behaviour by including minor changes in the code
- Also, when **debugging**, the 3 threads (each one opens its own `InputStream` and a `BufferedReader` for the same config file) work perfectly

---

#### ANSWER

**Effectively, `InputStreams` can be created in different threads, all pointing to the same file, and then be read using a `BufferedReader` without synchronizing anything.**

My first mistake was showing here a too reduced version of the original code. I focused on showing what I thought that was the problem. It is my first post, I'll do better next time.

The error in my code was in the `getConfig` method, which builds the `fileName` using the panel and subpanel parameters. This method, before returning this `fileName` variable, downloads the file from a server (only if it has changed) to the `target/` dir to be accessed locally. What was working **wrong** is that the file was being downloaded **always**, so it was being re-downloaded (overwritten) by another thread while being read in current thread.

Find below the code I should have placed in the post originally:

```java
// REST CONTROLLER

@GetMapping(value = "/schema/{panel}/{subpanel}")
public PanelSchemaEntity getSchema(String panel, String subpanel)
{
  //Retrieves the config-file name associated to the given panel+subpanel
  ConfigFile configFile = getConfig(panel, subpanel);
  // configFile.getPath() = "target/config/panelABC1.txt"

  InputStream input = new FileInputStream(configFile.getPath());
  PanelSchemaEntity schema = new PanelSchemaEntity();
  parseFile(schema, input);

  return schema;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/data/{panel}/{subpanel}")
public PanelDataEntity get(String panel, String subpanel)
{
  //Retrieves the config-file name associated to the given panel+subpanel
  ConfigFile configFile = getConfig(panel, subpanel);
  // configFile.getPath() = "target/config/panelABC1.txt"

  InputStream input = new FileInputStream(configFile.getPath());
  PanelSchemaEntity schema = new PanelSchemaEntity();
  parseFile(schema, input);

  String dataFileName = getDataFile(panel, subpanel);
  // dataFileName = "target/config/panelABC1.dat"
  InputStream data = new FileInputStream(dataFileName);

  return new PanelDataEntity(schema, data);
}
```

```java
// PLACED IN SOME UTILS PACKAGE

// Creates fileName and downloads file (if changed)
public ConfigFile getConfig(String panel, String subpanel)
{
  String filePathInServer = findFilePathInServer(panel, subpanel);

  // ERROR here: the download was happening always
  String localFilePath = donwloadIfChanged(filePathInServer); 

  ConfigFile configFile = new ConfigFile(localFilePath);

  return configFile;
}
```

```java
// PLACED IN SOME UTILS PACKAGE

// Fills the PanelSchemaEntity with the content read from input
public PanelSchemaEntity parseFile(PanelSchemaEntity schema, InputStream input)
{
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
  String nextLine = reader.readLine();

  // The data file is read and used to complete panel schema entity
  while(nextLine != null)
  {
    // Here goes the code that uses each line's content to 
    // fill some schema's attributes
  }
  reader.close();
  return schema;
}
```

When I moved the InputStream creation within the `getInputStream` method, I also included there the download of the file. This is why synchronizing the whole `getInputStream = download file + create and return InputStream` worked for me.

This requires to fix things in different places:
* I need to download file only when it has changed (as expected)
* I would also synchronize the whole `download + InputStream creation` for the case when the file is the same (not using the `fileName` string)

Comment: If the file you're reading from is small, you're regularly reading from the same file, and you rarely update the file, consider caching the `PanelSchemaEntity` from each file. Guava has some caching utilities for example, and should work with concurrent access. Just make sure to invalidate the cache every time you update the file.

Guava's CacheBuilder, if you don't want to make your own cache: https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Comment: Thank you @simonsays, I think that's a good idea, but I'm afraid I am not allowed to use Guava library, or any new library unless it is extremely necesary. Effectively, the file is small and it is rarely updated, but I cannot store it in cache.

Comment: Your code leaks resources if there are exceptions. Use try-with-resources.

Comment: Hi Please share xml file

Comment: Is this the real code? Are you sure that the `FileInputStream` and `BufferedReader` are local variables? Not instance or static variables?

Comment: Sometimes writing to the file would explain it. Trry-with-resources definitely is a must. The charset encoding is the default one. That could be changed dynamically & globally. Better specify the charset in InputStreamReader. The PanelSchemaEntity as other player you probably already inspected

Comment: @user207421 This is not the real code, it is a modified extraction of the original code since the original code cannot be placed here. I know including original code is really helpfull, but I am not allowed. Maybe I explained it wrong, sorry. `InputStream` is created locally at controller level. Deeper, inside the parser, the `BufferedReader` is created and closed. I don't see the need of making them static, but I started learning programming by myself short ago, and I may be wrong

Comment: I didn't say anything about making them static. Don't do that. They *must* be local variables. *Not* static, and not instance members. I'm sure this is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your question as a suggestion. They are local variables, created for each read-request. I have also read an old [issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5073414) related to openJDK, but it is solved. This makes me think there could be an issue when creating an InputStream of the same file at the same time?

Comment: That issue is about empty strings, not nulls, and it only occurs when multiple threads are sharing the same buffered reader, which is a degenerate case anyway. I'm convinced that either this or a shared file input stream is your problem. But I would also ask why you're reading the file twice at all? Can't you cache it?

Comment: This is performed this way because the web browser shows different panels, and each panel has many sub-panels.
When clicking a sub-panel, three different REST `get` requests happen. Each of these three `get` requests reads the same file (THE ONE), which containts the configuration of the presented sub-panel. But later, each `get` flow does different things with this information. There are hundreds of sub-panels, each of them has its own configuration file (read three times when sub-panel is opened) I cannot cache the file because it can be modified often and there are too much of these

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to concurrency. See here is the example of reading files simultaneously.
Concurrency could occur in the case of writing and reading files simultaneously. But for reading files there is no issue of data inconsistency or concurrency.

Pleae make necessary changes to following code to run.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "/home/note.xml";
    FileReadThread frth1 = new FileReadThread(fileName, "ThreadOne");
    FileReadThread frth2 = new FileReadThread(fileName, "ThreadTwo");
    FileReadThread frth3 = new FileReadThread(fileName, "ThreadThree");
    frth1.start();
    frth2.start();
    frth3.start();
}}



private String fileName;
private String threadName;
public FileReadThread(String fileName, String threadName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.threadName = threadName;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String strCurrentLine;
        while ((strCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(threadName + "--" + strCurrentLine);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried what you proposed, but each thread prints the whole file before the next thread starts, so the input files are not being read at the same time. This is really similar to what it is already implemented, except for the fact that my threads are created as a reaction to front-end request

Comment: Please run the program multiple times so that you would get a different output which contains arbitrary thread response means they are running parallelly

Comment: My fault, I was executing directly the `run` method of each thread instead of starting them.
Effectively, in this case the ouputs are printed mixed, as desired. But the problem remains when including this in the existing code. This still leads to `BufferedReader.readLine()` returning null, sometimes in the middle of the file, sometimes from the beginning (reading nothing at all).
Apparently, synchronizing the creation of the `InputStream` solves my problem. I have included it in a new answer, and will appreciate any comment.
Anyways, thanks for your effort and for being so didactic

Comment: There is nothing here that either proves your first sentence, which is most improbable, or answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for my case is the following:

```java
//REST CONTROLLER
@GetMapping(value = "/schema/{panel}/{subpanel}")
public PanelSchemaEntity getSchema(String panel, String subpanel)
{
  //Retrieves the config-file name associated to the given panel+subpanel
  String fileName = getConfig(panel, subpanel);
  // fileName = "target/config/panelABC1.txt"

  InputStream input = getInputStream(fileName);
  PanelSchemaEntity schema = new PanelSchemaEntity();
  return parseFile(schema, input);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/data/{panel}/{subpanel}")
public PanelDataEntity get(String panel, String subpanel)
{
  //Retrieves the config-file name associated to the given panel+subpanel
  String fileName = getConfig(panel, subpanel);
  // fileName = "target/config/panelABC1.txt"

  InputStream input = getInputStream(fileName);
  PanelSchemaEntity schema = new PanelSchemaEntity();
  parseFile(schema, input);

  String dataFileName = getDataFile(panel, subpanel);
  // dataFileName = "target/config/panelABC1.dat"
  InputStream data = new FileInputStream(dataFileName);
  return new PanelDataEntity(schema, data);
}
```

```java
// PLACED IN SOME UTILS PACKAGE

public InputStream getInputStream(String file)
{
  synchronize (file)
  {
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  }
}

// Fills the PanelSchemaEntity with the content read from input
public PanelSchemaEntity parseFile(PanelSchemaEntity schema, InputStream input)
{
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
  String nextLine = reader.readLine();

  // The data file is read and used to complete panel schema entity
  while(nextLine != null)
  {
    // Here goes the code that uses each line's content to 
    // fill some schema's attributes
  }
  reader.close();
  return schema;
}
```

Moving the InputStream initialisation to `getInputStream` method, which synchronises when the files are the same.

Please, feel free to make any correction. I appreciate them

Comment: You can use Lock or ReentrantLock instead of the synchronized keyword as it gives you more flexibility over concurrency handling.

Comment: Ok I have read about it, and definitely using Lock API is way much better than using a String as synchronisation monitor. I'll implement it and post it

Comment: The `getInputStream()` method is pointless. It creates an input stream and then throws it away. There is nothing here that would fix the problem.

Comment: @user207421 by printing traces, I checked that when my pointless `getInputStream` is not synchronized, one/some file/files suddenly stops being read, or is not read at all. Also, sometimes the three requests are OK and the three read-operations of the same file work.
Synchronizing the creation of the InputStream is the only thing that has **worked** for me, I'm not saying is the best approach. I have also tried synchronizing other blocks, but failed. I'm going to try using a ReentrantLock instead, which I find useful, but I'm all ears if there is any better solution since I'm here to learn

Comment: You're not synchronizing anything. The filename string is dynamic, created from the request in each case, so it isn't pooled. And the resulting input stream isn't even used. In fact it is leaked. . There is some other explanation.

Comment: When debugging, I checked that 2/3 threads that read this same filed were waiting to the 1/3 thread to return the InputStream. I noticed after posting this that using the String as "blocking" condition is wrong, but somehow it is working. I will use java Lock API instead(which I am currently learning how to use)

Comment: @user207421 I found the mistake, which had nothing to do with the post title. Definitely, I should have included more/better content in the original code example. Find the solution in the post body, (If you want to read such a Bible). Thanks for your comments, and for staying firm. I'll do better next time